# CompletableFuture thenCombine return type inference

Tags: asynchronous, java-8, concurrency, completable-future

I have following two completable futures which I am trying to combine in a bifunction and tryign to obtain a CompletableFuture<List. Here is my code:

```
                CompletableFuture<ACR> contracts = getContracts(planNumber);
                CompletableFuture<MAR> money = getMoney(planNumber);
```

// getContracts and getMoney invoke supplyAsync

```
                CompletableFuture<List<InvestmentsResponse>> investmentResponsesFuture = money money.thenCombine(contracts , (moneyResponse, contractsResponse ) -> getInvestments(moneyResponse, contractsResponse , omniPlanNumber));
```

// Type mismatch here on above line
The compiler says:
//Required: CompletableFuture<list>
//Provided: CompletableFuture
// I am trying to understand why is thenCombine not being able to infer the return type CompletableFuture<List>

Here is the getInvestments method:

```
private CompletableFuture<List<InvestmentsResponse>> getInvestments(MoneyAvailabilityResponse moneyAvailabilityResponse, AnnuityContractsResponse annuityContractsResponse, String omniPlanNumber) {
    List<CompletableFuture<InvestmentsResponse>> completableFuturesList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (null != annuityContractsResponse.getAnnuityContracts()) {
        for (AnnuityContract annuityContract : annuityContractsResponse.getAnnuityContracts()) {
          
              completableFuturesList.add(getInvestmentsFromPrism(omniPlanNumber, annuityContract.getTypeCode()));
            
        }
    }
    return allOf(completableFuturesList);
}


private static <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> allOf(List<CompletableFuture<T>> futuresList) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> allFuturesResult =
            CompletableFuture.allOf(futuresList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
    return allFuturesResult.thenApply(v ->
            futuresList.stream().
                    map(CompletableFuture::join).
                    collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
}
```

What can i do to resolve this? // please see the comments which tells the issue

I managed to simply return List from getInvestments by doing a join and then was able to receive CompletableFuture<List> on the third line, however I am not sure if that is a correct way of using CompletableFuture since I am invoking the blocking join before the paralellism has to end supposedly

Comment: The problem with copy-pasting the parts of your project without all the types and methods (i.e. `InvestmentsResponse`, `getInvestmentsFromPrism`) is that it makes it very hard for anyone to copy this into their IDE and make it compile. If you want an answer, make it as easy as possible to help you. That means removing the irrelevant parts. Use dummy classes, or ones already in the JDK.

Comment: You would need to combine into an intermediate type (a record of two values) and use `thenCompose` with the future from `getInvestmentsFromPrism`.

Comment: @BenManes can you kindly elaborate. I can generalise the code as suggested by Michael above

Comment: ```List<X> list = future1.thenCombine(future2, (value1, value2) -> Pair.of(value1, value2)).thenCompose(pair -> loadAll(pair.first(), pair.second());``` - This means you resolve the two arguments, combine them into an intermediate value, and "compose" by deconstructing the pair to call the bulk method that returns a future with a list result.

Comment: Thank you so much @BenManes . It worked perfectly. Just saw your profile, man you are a legend !! thanks again